# How to add firebase app check in android app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I have [registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJReF.png) app check-in firebase for a flutter app. But I couldn't find mainactivity file in my android folder

**path/to-java:**

```
---- android
  ---- app
   --- src
    --- main
      --- java
       -- io
          --- flutter 
            --- plugins
                 --- GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
```

[GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmJZS.png)

**path/to-kotlin:**

```
---- android
  ---- app
   --- src
    --- main
      --- kotlin
        --- com
          -- company
           ---- app-name
             ---- MainActivity.kt
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.company.app_name

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

I have referred [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/usage) but i don't know where to add the files exactly can someone help with that? Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? i dont see anything in the link you provided about adding files to your project

Comment: They mentioned to add the following line in mainactivity.java file but i don't have any mainactivity.java
`import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
    DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()); `

Comment: Did u find any solution to this bro? Been sitting on it over 3 days now :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create the class file MainActivity.java and It should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

and if it does not work, try:

```
flutter create -a java .
```

Try this command. with '.' at end. It represent current project directory. apply this command from project root folder. This command will try to recreate android project with java (this will setup your MainActiviy.java). It won't affect currently setup manifest or any other firebase related setup.

Comment: Can i remove kotlin folder and mainactivity.kt ?

Comment: It seems like there is no problema if you delete it